# Finding nearest neighbor for each point in the same table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, performance, knn

We've got a table of approximately 300,000 points and would like to find the nearest neighbor (within 10km) to each point in the same table. The most efficient query we've found so far is below, but it's slow enough that it's basically unworkable ... hasn't run to completion after multiple hours.  Geometry is EPSG:4326, PostGIS 2.1.8.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON(p1.id) p1.id AS p1_id,
    p2.id AS p2_id,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(p1.geom, p2.geom)
FROM
    points p1, points p2
WHERE
    p1.id <> p2.id AND st_dwithin(p1.geom, p2.geom, 10000)
ORDER BY
    p1.id,
    st_distance_sphere(p1.geom,p2.geom);
```

We've also tried a couple of other options including using the PostGIS KNN operator and looping through points individually using a cursor function.

Is there a more efficient query we can use, or maybe improved nearest neighbor support in newer versions of PostGIS?

Comment: Do you want to find only closest point to each point (relation one to one) or find any point from given point within distance (one points to many points)?

Comment: In this case only the closest point.

Comment: did you get this to work? did any answer here help?

Answer (score 18):

This is essentially a duplicate question of multiple others, with the sole difference being a table self-join.

However, all queries currently present in this post have delicate CRS misunderstandings, at least when it comes to distances:

- the main problem here is the threshold given to `ST_DWithin`; the units of that value are CRS dependent, thus, as the data is in EPSG:4236, you are searching in a radius of 10000 **degrees**!
- follow-up problem is the actual distance a degree represents in suface distance; one degree of Longitude **does not** represent the same suface distance over different Latitudes!

Arguably the best way to realize true *KNN* searches uses the `LATERAL JOIN` in conjunction with the `<->` *KNN* operator, and, optionally but likely not required, a limiting radius filter (e.g. `ST_DWithin` or `ST_Expand` + `&&` *BBox* comparator).

Concerning the units, one could choose a *on-the-fly* cast to *geography* type to tackle the CRS/distance issues *and* get the most precise distances in one go, using speroidal (or, quicker, spherical) algebra.

Runing

```
SELECT p1.id AS p1_id,
       p2.id AS p2_id,
       ST_Distance(p1.geom::geography, p2.geom::geography) AS dist
FROM   points AS p1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT id,
         geom
  FROM   points
  WHERE  p1.id <> id
 -- AND  ST_DWithin(p1.geom::geography, geom::geography, 10000)
  ORDER BY
         p1.geom::geography <-> geom::geography
  LIMIT  1
) AS p2
;
```

will return `dist` in *meter* to the nearest neighbor `p2.id` for each `p1.id`.
Note: due to the cast to *geography*, units for any accepting function will be in *meter* as well, thus the `10000` again.

As already mentioned, it is **essential** that you have a proper index in place! Checking the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is crucial to find out if it is actually used (although you can tell it is if you get results within your lifetime I guess...), and running `VACUUM ANALYZE <table_name>` in advance can help to enforce its use.
Now, the liberal use of the *on-the-fly* cast to *geography* will take a heavy toll on execution speed. I´d recommend to either **project the data to a suitable projection** for distance measurements of your area, **or, possibly better, change the *geometry* type to *geography***; both can be achieved by adding a new column, if you want your original `geom`s to stay untouched, and **add an own index** to it.
Using test data on 70.000 points with porperly indexed *geography* column (having added a second one) took about 1 min. to complete the initial, uncached run on a mid tech setup.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Life saver for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use <-> function with 2D index on geometry.

```
CREATE INDEX points_geom ON points USING GIST(geom)
```

After that you can do it something like that if you want to find only the closest point to another point (one to one relation)

```
SELECT
  first_point.*,
  second_points.*,
  st_distance(first_point.geom, second_points.geom) distance
FROM (SELECT
        p1.id     as p1_id,
        (SELECT p2.id
         FROM points p2
         WHERE p1.id <> p2.id AND ST_DWithin(p1.geom, p2.geom, 10000)
         ORDER BY p1.geom <-> p2.geom
         LIMIT 1) AS p2_id
      FROM points p1) knn
  LEFT JOIN points first_point ON first_point.id = knn.p1_id
  LEFT JOIN points second_points ON second_points.id = knn.p1_id;
```

If you are strugling with performance add EXPLAIN at the beginning to check if your indexes are in use.