# Is PostGIS ST_Distance equivalent to QGIS distance to hub?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'd like to make the equivalent function of QGIS's distance to hub algorithms. Is ST_Distance the right approach to start with? Or is that algorithm transposable into something I can let Postgres PostGIS?

Comment: depends on the parameters you parse to St_Distance. If you parse the ST_Union of your hubs the result could be the same I guess.

Comment: it's not eqivalent, but has to be utilized in order to mimic the QGIS functionality; what you're after is a *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search. @RutgerH, your suggestion *does* work as expected; currently, the most performant (and versatile) solution to this, even on large tables, should however be a `LATERAL JOIN` construct using the `<->` *KNN* operator; the spatial index will be used to it's full potential (whereas the on-the-fly `ST_Union/ST_Collect` geometry can't). check a [working exampe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287810/93656) (yes, it's my own answer...) for the general structure.

Comment: @ThingumaBob many thanks for this, I've tried adapting your example but it's not giving the same results as QGIS as posted https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307701/posgis-knn-returns-different-results-from-qgis-hub-spoke-function

Answer (score 1):

Yeah should be very simple:

```
select a.id, b.id, st_distance(a.geom, b.geom)
from
hub_table a,
locations_table b
```

Which would get the distance to all points from all hubs.