# PosGIS KNN returns different results from QGIS hub spoke function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, postgis-2.3, postgresql-10

Following example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287774/nearest-neighbor/287810#287810) I have tried to get nearest neighbours where code is;

```
CREATE TABLE model.hub_spoke_spokes3f AS
SELECT 
   hub.id AS hub_id,
   spoke.id,
   spoke.point_geom,
   ST_Distance(hub.geom, spoke.point_geom) AS dist
FROM hub_data.geom_data_unique AS hub
JOIN LATERAL (
SELECT id,
     point_geom
FROM spoke_data.data_set
WHERE ST_DWithin(hub.geom, point_geom, 150000) --geom is 277000, units metres 
AND hub.id <> id
ORDER BY hub.geom <-> point_geom
LIMIT 100
) AS spoke
ON TRUE;
```

I then compared the results with QGIS Hub and spoke function which I was trying to replicate.

[image]

As screen shot below the results differ. The lines are created by QGIS but the spokes (smaller dots) are from the query above. Whats causing the difference?

Comment: Are both the input geometries points, because, the <-> operator calculates closest distance to any point, while the <#> operator calculates distance using bounding boxes, which for anything other than points or circles, will likely give different results. I have absolutely no idea how the QGIS function operates, so this is a guess.

Comment: Thank you, yes both are point. Documentation for QGIS function here; https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/HubDistanceLines.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of the join is crucial here; your query selects *the 100 nearest points (with different id) to each hub* (and cross-joins them with the respective hub), whereas you rather want to select *the one closest hub to each point*.

The `LATERAL` join will execute the *right hand* (table) expression for each row of the *left hand* table.

Running

```
CREATE TABLE model.hub_spoke_spokes3f AS
  SELECT b.id AS hub_id,
         a.id AS spoke_id,
         ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) AS dist,
         a.point_geom
         -- ST_MakeLine(b.geom, a.geom) AS spoke_geom
  FROM   spoke_data.data_set AS a
  JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT q.id,
           q.geom
    FROM   hub_data.geom_data_unique AS q
    ORDER BY
           q.geom <-> a.geom
    LIMIT  1
  ) AS b
  ON true;
```

will assign the `hub_id` of the closest hub to each of your points. With the (out-commented) `ST_MakeLine` you will get the corresponding lines between them.

*I used to get just a bit better performance with the `ON true` construct; since PostgreSQL > 10, this has become equal to `<table_a>, LATERAL (<expression>)` or `<table_a> CROSS JOIN LATERAL (<expression>)`. Not sure why.*

---

Note that this is slightly different to the 'Join by lines (hub lines) - Hub and Spokes' function, that connects points to hubs with lines (*spokes*) based on a common attribute. If I get that right, you would then just join both tables on e.g. `hub.id = spoke.hub_id`.

Comment: Thank you and for the explanation, that gives the results as expected

Comment: well spotted and well explained.